# Access VBA editing textbox of another form referenced by variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hello world of Stackoverflow, I'm working on an access database and got a question about VBA, I'm pretty much a noob at it but I manage, just for this problem I haven't found a fitting solution yet.

I want to replace the Form name in

```
[Forms]![Exampleform]![Examplefield] = "exampletext"
```

with a variable so for example:

```
[Forms]![-Variable-]![Examplefield] = "exampletext"
```

From what I've managed to find out it can be done like this

```
Forms(-Variable-).Controls(Examplefield)
```

but how do I edit the text of the Examplefield in this way?

Comment: ```Forms(FrmName).Controls(CtlName).Value = "TestVal"```

Comment: It doesn't quite work for me, I'm replacing FrmName with the name of the form and CtlName with the name of the Textbox, am I doing something wrong there? :p

Comment: As shown above but not any variable name - the form's or control's actual name wrapped in `"` quotes e.g `"Examplefield"`.

Comment: ahh yes that's it! Thank you :)